# Where can I find a pre-trained variational autoencoder that's trained on natural images?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mxnet, pre-trained-model

Does anyone know a pre-trained variational autoencoder (VAE) or a VAE-GAN that's trained on natural images?

I have been searching for a variational autoencoder that is trained on natural images (e.g. ImageNet) where I can extract latent features from. It could be implemented in any framework, preferably MXNet, Chainer or PyTorch.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE.

The models were all trained on the celebrity faces dataset CelebA.